# Making list items scroll while scrolling list view

Tags: android-listview

I am trying to implement a custom list view. When it scrolls vertically, the list item should expand only from the top (not expanding both top and bottom, but just the top). It's to give a totally different animating effect to the whole scroll functionality. Any ideas on how to do this?

I tried setting an onScrollListener() on the list view and am trying to increase the height of the list item cells when i get the callback in the onScroll() method but it doesnt seem to be the right way to do things. Any ideas?